# "Please specify the product's option(s)" in Magento.

Tags: magento

In Magento, I am using bundled products and I have a configurable product as an associated product of the bundled product. This configurable product has 4 simple product as associated products of the configurable product.

The chain goes like:
 - bundle product - configurrable product (associated with bundled product) - simple products (associated with configurable products)

Now, in the bundled product view page in the frontend, I'm getting this message:

> Please specify product option(s)

although I have filled out all the required fields for all the products as required,

This validation error message occurs while adding the product to the cart.

Any advice? I've been stuck for day with this problem.

Comment: As an aside, the only answer you've ever accepted is your own. You may get better results in the future if you go back and accept correct answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Andrey's answer, if you want a configurable product in a bundle that includes required options, you'll need to modify the templates to output the product options during rendering. If there are price differences, you'll basically be rewriting the JS to support the dynamic pricing mechanism on the page.

Once the form is submitted, you'll need to modify the cart classes and controllers to support saving the product options as the items are placed in the cart. You'll also need to override pricing as before to support whatever custom pricing this entails. Make sure that the cart resource classes properly save the simple products underneath the configurable products underneath the bundle product.

I've probably missed several items. This is why it is currently not supported. :/

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

For others experiencing this message with a different product configuration...

The underlying error message can be easily reproduced via the standard Magento admin screens (any downloadable added to a group or bundle will cause it - regardless of the "link can be purchased separately" setting).

In the case of grouped or bundled downloadable products, this is a known bug (see http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=10864). The bug report describes a suitable fix for these, and although it is supposed to have been patched in newer distributions, remains unresolved in Magento ver. 1.5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not support bundle products with selections of products that have some required options (configurables, downloadables with links, simple products with any required option and so on).

Your configuration is not valid for a system and not supported. In fact Magento does not show mentioned above products as a possible choice for bundle option selection. If you were able to make such a bundle using standard Magento admin panel - report a bug with detailed step-by-step case at http://www.magentocommerce.com