# Image upload magento v1.9 not working?

Tags: magento, image-uploading, magento-1.9

I have a website and I need customers to upload images on our website for printing them on products. So, I have tried the custom option in magento but it did not work for me, it every times give me the following error

> please specify the product's required option(s).

Here is the [link](http://www.shopeling.com/handmade-wall-hanging.html) for the product

Please provide a solution

Note : It is a simple product and I have added all the required option(s).

Comment: I dont mean to span anything but I want is a simple answer that how do I upload an image in magento..?

Comment: Is there any code you could include in the question? And probably take out that first link to your website, since it isn’t needed for the question and makes it look like an advertisement.

Comment: Sorry I will do that..

Comment: Also I dont know which code to mention in this question because I have no idea about this?

Comment: I don’t know either. I need to get off my computer now, but if you can think of any way of adding more information to the question, it would help. It’s best if people can answer your question based only on the question as written here, rather than asking people to visit your site. Maybe someone else will come along with suggestions or an answer.

Comment: K then thanks I will see if I can get some related code

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this error is *not* related to image uploading! it can happen under different circumstances mainly because one missing required parameter prevents Magento (or better to say *add to cart controller*) to add the product to the cart (this follows the logic that Magento should know what exact simple product is to be added to the cart). Have a look at these related questions: first this one: [1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16560/magento-please-specify-the-product-required-options-error), then: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199152/please-specify-the-products-options-configurable-product-magento?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937823/magento-please-specify-the-products-options-message-remains-after-completin), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155242/please-specify-the-products-options-in-magento?rq=1). Eventually if you have used some code please add it to your question (what do you mean by you've tried the custom option?).

On the other hand if your case is just with uploading the image you can use: `Varien_File_Uploader` class in Magento [(example)](http://blog.decryptweb.com/file-upload-magento/).

IMPO You can change your current logic by removing the upload option from product page, first letting the customer to add the product to the cart and then in next step upload their image(s).